# Can a Windows11 VM hosted on Azure autologin?

Tags: windows, azure

A user is running a 3rd party program on a Windows11 VM on Azure. Because the program isn't a service, whenever the instance reboots (e.g. after a system update), user has to RDP into an instance and login, which causes the software to start. This is annoying, because it's important that it runs 24/7, or close.

Has to be Windows11, can't be Windows Server, because program relies on Docker Desktop, which doesn't run on Windows Server.

Doesn't necessarily have to be Azure, but Azure is the only cloud computing platform that runs Windows11 machines AFAIK.

How does one force login after reboot, while still keeping the host secure?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-login-automatically-to-windows-11/c0e9301e-392e-445a-a5cb-f44d00289715) will help?

Comment: Good idea, but that leaves the VM open to the world. Anyone can RDP. Can of course enable only one IP address, but this is meant for non-technical users. 

Maybe Azure can keep the password and login? Or maybe a script can do that? Or perhaps there is a setting that logs in behind a locked screen? Long shot I know.

Comment: Maybe you can just [run your application as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2869826/1790644)?

Comment: Can a service have GUI?